# Pandas groupby diff removes column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this:

```
d = {'id': ['101_i','101_e','102_i','102_e'], 1: [3, 4, 5, 7], 2: [5,9,10,11], 3: [8,4,3,7]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

[image: df]

I want to subtract all rows which have the same prefix id, i.e. subtract all values of rows 101_i with 101_e or vice versa. The code I use for that is:

```
df['new_identifier'] = [x.upper().replace('E', '').replace('I','').replace('_','') for x in df['id']]
df = df.groupby('new_identifier')[df.columns[1:-1]].diff().dropna()
```

I get the output like this:

[image: df2]

I see that I lose the new column that I create, `new_identifier`. Is there a way I can retain that?

Answer (score 2):

You can define specific aggregation function (in this case `np.diff()` for columns 1, 2, and 3) for columns that you know the types (int or float in this case).

```py
import numpy as np
df.groupby('new_identifier').agg({i: np.diff for i in range(1, 4)}).dropna()
```

Result:

```
                1  2  3
new_identifier         
101             1  4 -4
102             2  1  4
```

Comment: I think agg is slow than GroupBy.diff

Answer (score 1):

[`Series.str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) to get groups, you need [`DataFrame.set_axis()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_axis.html) before `GroupBy`, after that we use [`GroupBy.diff`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.diff.html)

```
cols = df.columns.difference(['id'])
groups = df['id'].str.split('_').str[0]

new_df = (

df.set_axis(groups, axis=0)
.groupby(level=0)
[cols]
.diff()
.dropna()
)

print(new_df)
       1    2    3
id                
101  1.0  4.0 -4.0
102  2.0  1.0  4.0
```

**Detail Groups**

```
df['id'].str.split('_').str[0]

0    101
1    101
2    102
3    102
Name: id, dtype: object
```